# how to get out value of one procedure into another procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two procedure namely "createOrder" And "createAndress"

And in "createOrder" procedure i have 4 IN parameter and 1 out parameter.

And in "createAndress" procedure i have 3 IN parameter and 1 out parameter.

And i am calling "createAndress" inside the "createOrder" procedure like below

```
CALL create_address (in_userprofile_id, in_pin, true, in_address_id);
```

but how to get out value of "createAndress" into "createOrder" procedure ?

Comment: Sounds like a quick internet search should be easy enough: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do this inside your `CreateOrder` stored proc

```
 -- Declare the variable to receive the output value of the procedure.
      DECLARE @OutParameterForCreateAddress INT;
 -- Execute the procedure specifying in_userprofile_id, in_pin, true,in_address_id for the input parameter
 -- and saving the output value in the variable @OutParameterForCreateAddress 
      EXECUTE create_address in_userprofile_id, in_pin, true, in_address_id,    @YourOutParameterNameinCreatedAddress = @OutParameterForCreateAddress OUTPUT;
 -- Display the value returned by the procedure.
      Print @OutParameterForCreateAddress
```

Comment: @kushal Please try with this answer.